# Text Output from Class function? - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I apologize if I'm not using proper terminology, I'm new to Python and have been doing this leisurely for fun.  I'm trying to figure out everything myself by watching some tutorials, and reading online.  The problem I'm having is I wanted to make a GUI for a python password generator (very easy first project.)  I've created what I thought to be the correct format, but I'm having an issue with the function displaying in the GUI window rather than the terminal.  I think it's when I come to the self.output where it messes everything up.

```
class GenPass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame()
        frame.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Generate Password", padx=4, pady=4, command=self.generate)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Copy to Clipboard", padx=4, pady=4, command=master.destroy)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.output = Label(frame, fg="Green")
        self.output.place(x=240, y=85)
        self.output.config(text=self.generate)

    def generate(self):
        for i in range(3):
            print(random.choice(Words).capitalize(), end='')
        for i in range(2):
            print(random.choice(Numbers), end='')
        for i in range(1):
            print(random.choice(Spec_Char))
```

I expect the outcome to be in the GUI window, there would be the generated password.  It comes up in the terminal, but not in the window.  When it does come up by making tweaks to the output.pack() it just lists random numbers and the name of the function (ex. 9012381generate)

Comment: You should `return` the password from your `generate()` method. `print` will print it to the console.

Comment: better inside `generate` use `self.output.config(text=)` instead of `print()` - but first create one string with all letters and then use `self.output.config(text=)`

Answer (score 1):

Inside `generate` you should create string with password and use `self.output.config(text=password)` instead of `print()`.

I changed code because it didn't work for me. Now everyone can copy code and run it.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import string

words = string.ascii_uppercase
numbers = string.digits
spec_char = '!@#$%'

class GenPass:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master) # add parent for Frame
        frame.pack()

        self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Generate Password", padx=4, pady=4, command=self.generate)
        self.printButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text="Copy to Clipboard", padx=4, pady=4, command=master.destroy)
        self.quitButton.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.output = Label(master, fg="Green")
        self.output.pack()

        self.generate() # genrate password at start


    def generate(self):
        password = ''
        for i in range(3):
            password += random.choice(words)
        for i in range(2):
            password += random.choice(numbers)
        for i in range(1):
            password += random.choice(spec_char)
        self.output.config(text=password)


root = Tk()
GenPass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

BTW: every widget should have parent so I add `master` in `Frame()`. Maybe it makes no difference here but if you would have many frames or widgets then widget without parent can be displayed in unexpected place.

`pack()` and `place()` and `grid()` shouldn't be mixed in one window or frame because `pack()` and `grid()` try to calculate position dynamically and other layour manager can makes problem with it. But using  `pack/grid/place` you can put `frame` and inside this `frame` you can use different layour manager (`pack/grid/place`).

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible that the 'words = string.ascii_uppercase' to actually be pointing to a text document with dictionary words instead?

Comment: yes, you can use `list()` with words. Using `dict()` you would have to use `choice(words.values())`. And you can read words from file - if you have every word in separated line `words = open(filename).read().split('\n')`

Comment: ...and from python 3.6 you can use...https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html